# linear-gradient doesn't work when applied to body

Tags: html, css

When I apply a linear gradient to the body in CSS like below

```
body 
{
background: linear-gradient(#10416b, black); 
}
```

It doesn't apply it to the entire web page, instead what happens is it is applied to the first half of the page, and then starts over from blue to black for the second half, (#10416b is a blue color). Adding in height:100%; to the body doesn't change anything.

I fixed the problem by doing the below in CSS

```
.background {
  background: linear-gradient(#10416b, black);
  height: 100%; 

}
```

and this in HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html class="background"> 
 // lots of unrelated code in between the tags  
</html>
```

But I still don't understand why setting the background with the linear gradient in the body didn't work. If somebody could explain this to me that would be great.

Comment: if body is empty or filled with element in position fixed or absolute (or eventually only floating elements), it has an height of 0. where a color will be applied to html a gradient will be repeated using the height of body. if body has an height of zero, gradient will not be shown. just add a padding to your empty body and see what happens then :) see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGyzap and http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGoExQ to see what happens here too

Comment: I think ur right about the body height, but setting a padding in the body doesn't have any effect on the background color

Comment: ?? are talking about color or gradient ?  : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGyzap hover html to increase padding on body  and see ....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use 100vh instead of 100%

```
   body {
      height: 100vh;
      background: linear-gradient(#10416b, black); 
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r77r0cco/1/

`body` in and of itself doesn't have a height, so it looks to its parent element `<html>` which, because it has no content, also has no height.

`vh` uses the viewport dimensions instead of a parent element's

Comment: Thanks I think I understand now

Answer (score 4):

The body has no height of it's own as such without the HTML having a height or the body containing content.Then the gradient will repeat because `repeat` is the default in the `background` shorthand property.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#10416b, black);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think I understand know. So once I set the html height then the body will have the height of the html tag?

Comment: Way prettier solution!

Comment: Wouldn't `min-height` be a better fit for this purpose? With `height`, the gradient will start over if you pass the `100%` limit. This isn't the case with `min-height`, because `html` will automatically resize when you decide to pass the 100% height

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly, I'd like to thank @Paulie_D who inspired me to come up with this answer.**

---

Below you can see 2 methods to get your body have a gradient background.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My awesome webpage</title>

        <style>
            html {
                min-height: 100%;    /* Unlike 'height', which is used by
                                        @Paulie_D, this will make your webpage
                                        automatically resize when it exceeds
                                        the 100% height, thus it won't start the
                                        gradient over
                                      */
            }

            body {
                background: linear-gradient(  180deg,

                                              #C0C0AA     0%,
                                              #1CEFFF   100%
                                          );
            }


            /***** Content design *****/

            #hello {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size:   5em;
                text-align:  center;

                color:       #424242;
                text-shadow: 0 0 1rem darkgray;

                transition:  0.25s;
            }

            #hello:hover {
                font-size:   100vh;
                color:       darkgray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="hello">Hover and scroll!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This method will automatically resize the gradient to fit the whole content.

---

If you want the gradient to be the size of the window height, you can use a `::before` pseudoelement on `body`, to draw a fix-positioned gradient with a `z-index` of `-1`. Like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My awesome webpage</title>

        <style>
            body::before {
                content: "";

                background: linear-gradient(  180deg,

                                              #C0C0AA     0%,
                                              #1CEFFF   100%
                                          );

                top:    0;
                bottom: 0;
                left:   0;
                right:  0;

                position: fixed;

                z-index: -1;
            }
            
            
            /***** Content design *****/

            #hello {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size:   5em;
                text-align:  center;

                color:       #424242;
                text-shadow: 0 0 1rem darkgray;

                transition:  0.25s;
            }

            #hello:hover {
                font-size:   100vh;
                color:       darkgray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="hello">
            Hover and scroll!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

###### Sorry, I don't usually answer Stack Overflow questions, but this was a top result of a Google query, so I couldn't resist. If you can improve this answer, please request an edit.